# default controller value / setting in codeigntier

Tags: codeigniter, controller, default

I have the following settings in my routes.php for my codeigniter application:

```
   $route['default_controller'] = 'Welcome';
```

And in my config file I have the following:

```
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://myserver/gpohelp/'
```

When i try navigating to either

```
     http://myserver/gpohelp/

     http://myserver/gpohelp/index.php
```

i get a 404 error.

But if i do the following, the page loads properly:

```
    http://myserver/gpohelp/index.php/Welcome
```

can you tell me what i'm doing wrong? i'm sure it's something simple, because the code works as is in my development environment.  I just move the app to a new server... and it's not happy.

Comment: Do you use `mod_rewrite`? Or did you setup your index file setting in `config.php` properly?

Comment: here's my index file setting:  $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

Comment: not using mod_rewrite right now...

Comment: Maybe you should try to make the controller class all lowercase in routes file? Change it in routes, but keep controller class name first letter capitalized. Please tell if it works

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to edit the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

as described in the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html)

Comment: it looks like that is only required though if i don't want the index.php as a part of my URL.  However, for now, I'd like to keep it there.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe your server is not configured to look for `index.php` first, and it might be looking for `index.html` which results in the 404.

Check your Apache logs to see, they should tell you the 404 file not found.
Because if you do `http://myserver/gpohelp/index.php/Welcome` and it works, that means it should work for:

```
http://myserver/gpohelp/index.php
```

so what happens if you try the above without `/Welcome`?

Comment: what server are you running? is it Apache? I'm guessing IIS?

Comment: and you have the PHP module setup correctly? Other php apps work fine?

Comment: stupid question from me, is your file called `welcome.php` or `Welcome.php`? As `$route['default_controller'] = 'Welcome';` is case sensitive (linux at least)... and URL is not...